# Manually verify SSL certificate in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, ssl-certificate

I have an Android `WebView` in which some https content is shown. There's an issue with the SSL certificate provided by the server. While I'm waiting for a new certificate that is trusted by the WebView I'm wondering how I can manually verify the SSL certificate.

I have `WebViewClient` in where I in `onReceivedSslError` receive an `SslError` with the primary error code of `SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED`. On the same error object I receive the certificate, an instance of `SslCertificate`.

Is there any way for me to do any manual verifications against that certificate object to verify that it is trustworthy?

I'm not interested in accepting all certificates even though this is a temporary thing.